# Java mysql - SELECT statements delaying main thread

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, asynchronous

Prior information: the database is hosted remotely and averages at 92ms delay to connect.

I have a little MySQL database which holds player data for my game.

Each player returns 250 rows when iterating through the resultSet, assigning the player variables on their login to the game.

My problem is that each time a player login, my game Main Thread gets delayed for a small time, about 200ms. (Each game cycle has 600ms).

I found out that's only happening with SELECT statements, all other queries as UPDATE, DELETE, or any query that doesn't return a ResultSet is just fine.

I'm using c3p0 MySQL Pool, here's my configs for it:

```
    cpds.setInitialPoolSize(100);
    cpds.setMinPoolSize(100);
    cpds.setNumHelperThreads(200);
    cpds.setMaxIdleTime(0);
    cpds.setAcquireIncrement(10);
    cpds.setMaxPoolSize(200);
    cpds.setMaxStatements(0);
```

Each time a player logs in, about 10 queries are executed, requesting information about other players around, about their current chat server etc. Those queries cannot be issued in a single statement, that's the reason of multiple threads and connections in c3p0, to reduce lag, which is working pretty well.

As I said, It is only happening with SELECT queries which expect a ResultSet.

The question is: How would I run that query, assign the result to the player variables, all that without messing up the main thread for 200ms?

200ms may see "ok", but what if 50 players are logging in at the same time? That just multiplies that time creating a massive thread-lock.

How I am loading the players:

On Login, this is requested:

```
PlayerLoader.load(username);
```

So the following method which returns the Player instance, gets called:

```
public static Player load(String name) {
    ResultSet result = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Player player = new Player();
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        con =  World.database().getConnection();
        ps =con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + PLAYER_TABLE + " WHERE username='" + name + "' LIMIT 1");
        result = ps.executeQuery();
        if (result.next()) {
            return player.playerSaving().load(result);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error Loading the account: "+name);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (result != null) {
                result.close();
            }
            result = null;
            ps.close();
            ps = null;
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

After getting the ResultSet, another method gets called, that will assign the variables to the player instance.

That method consists of:

```
        player.getPlayerDefinition().getIndex(result.getShort("id")).setDisplayName(result.getString("displayName"));
        player.getPlayerDefinition().setRights(result.getShort("rights"));
        player.getPlayerDefinition().setPlayTime(result.getLong("playTime"));
        player.getPlayerDefinition().setMuted(result.getInt("mute")).setMuteDuration(Long.parseLong(result.getString("muteTill")));
        player.getPlayerDefinition().setBanned(result.getLong("banned"));
        player.getPlayerDefinition().setPermBanned(result.getString("permBanned").equals("true"));
        player.getPlayerDefinition().setMemberDays2(result.getLong("member_days"));
```

That was just a short version of it. Currently it loads all 250 rows.

That method also returns the Player instance, so the first Load method will return it. (See: `public Player load(ResultSet result)`)

After that process, with the instance created and ready to proceed, the player now requests the information about their world, chat server, etc, and that's about 6-7 small queries which executes pretty fast also. About 2-3 of the queries are SELECT statements with a short result.

Again, is there any way to run that load process in a async thread? If yes so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that JDBC is blocking.

If you deploy your application to a web server then the effect of the blocking fashion can be reduced by using a thread pool. In that case the number of requests that can be served concurrently depends on the size of the thread pool.

Comment: I am currently using five dedicated servers. 4 of them is located in Canada, the main one, that is hosting the database is located in the US.

I am trying to make the remote performance good because I'm about to get more servers in Asia, because of pings in that location. However the database loading must be fast no matter where the client is located.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by simply creating another dedicated thread to process logins.

How the thread works:

- Player requests login
- Request is queued for execution which takes less than 10ms in a dedicated thread.
- Thread executes the Runnable, not delaying Main Thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can offload time-consuming operations to a different thread, and get event notifications when loading is done. This is analogous to the Swing UI event dispatch model, so you can read up on that: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/swingworker-137249.html